# Javascript validate date format (include the hyphens)

Tags: javascript, date

I have date inputs which I need to store as DD-MMM-YYYY. I have the code below to test. For the most part it does make sure the data is in DD MMM YYYY format, but I need to include the hyphens. For instance 01-JUN-2015 is said to be valid, but so is 01/JUN/2015. The second should fail. I have tried to include the hyphens without success.

```
function testDate(sender, args) {
    var result = isDate(document.getElementById('dateTest').value);
    console.log(document.getElementById('dateTest').value);
    console.log(result);
    $('#result').text(result);

}

//function isDate(txtDate) {
function isDate(currVal) {

    if (currVal == '') return false;

    //Declare Regex  
    var rxDatePattern = /^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(?:(\d{1,2})|(jan)|(feb)|(mar)|(apr)|(may)|(jun)|(jul)|(aug)|(sep)|(oct)|(nov)|(dec))(\/|-)(\d{4})$/i;

    var dtArray = currVal.match(rxDatePattern);

    if (dtArray == null) return false;

    var dtDay = parseInt(dtArray[1]);
    var dtMonth = parseInt(dtArray[3]);
    var dtYear = parseInt(dtArray[17]);

    if (isNaN(dtMonth)) {
        for (var i = 4; i <= 15; i++) {
            if ((dtArray[i])) {
                dtMonth = i - 3;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (dtMonth < 1 || dtMonth > 12) return false;
    else if (dtDay < 1 || dtDay > 31) return false;
    else if ((dtMonth == 4 || dtMonth == 6 || dtMonth == 9 || dtMonth == 11) && dtDay == 31) return false;
    else if (dtMonth == 2) {
        var isleap = (dtYear % 4 == 0 && (dtYear % 100 != 0 || dtYear % 400 == 0));
        if (dtDay > 29 || (dtDay == 29 && !isleap)) return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think I'd go with the moment.js library to do what you want to do. They have all of these mechanics worked out for you and then some:

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/

It's a lot less of a hassle and way more efficient than doing it yourself.

Comment: I unfortunately do not own the codebase and cannot add third party libraries. I need to complete it in native javascript.

Comment: just to be clear, you want 01-JUN-2015 to succeed and 01/JUN/2015 to fail? If so, those parts in the regexp are at fault: `(\/|-)` they should be `(-)`